# read characters and words in HTML text using javascript

Tags: javascript, string

consider that i am getting a HTML format string and 
want to read the number of words & characters,
Consider, i am getting,

```
var HTML =  '<p>BODY&nbsp;Article By Archie(Used By Story Tool)</p>';
```

now i want to get number of words and characters

above html will look like:

BODY Article By Archie(Used By Story Tool)

**IMPORTANT**

1. i want to avoid html **tags** while counting words or character
2. avoid keywords like  `**&nbsp;**` etc..
3. Ex. words and character should be counted of : (for current example)
   **BODY Article By Archie(Used By Story Tool)**

please help,
Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give an example for adamantium's suggestion:

```
var e = document.createElement("span");
e.innerHTML = '<p>BODY&nbsp;Article By Archie(Used By Story Tool)</p>';
var text = e.textContent || e.innerText;

var characterCount = text.length;
var wordCount = text.split(/[\s\.\(\),]+/).length;
```

Update: Added other word-stop characters

Comment: thanks for replying i have following query:  
the words can be separated by: 
blank space, fullstop,comma,opening round bracket(,closing round bracket ), dot . ,etc
how that can be done

**the above code is giving 9 word count it should be 8 i guess**  

pls reply

Comment: your earlier example worked with K Primes idea of using .match() of regExp ,anyways.
thanks for reply

Comment: and can you please tell how to identify number(digit) an same example
ie 
e.innerHTML ='<p>Super By My 4 Story</p>';
i want to ignore digit from word count

Comment: to eliminate numeric sections, you'd use something like: /\s+[0-9]+\s+|[\s\.\\(\\),]+/

Answer (score 2):

1. Use a hidden HTML element that can render text like span or p
2. Assign the string to the innerHTML of the hidden element.
3. Count the characters using length property of innerText/textContent.

To read the word count you can

1. Split the innerText/textContent using empty space
2. Get the length of the returned array.

Comment: Instead of `split`, I'd recommend using RegExp to take into account non-space breaks - for example, `text.match(/\b\w/g).length`

Comment: Note that split() can also take a regular expression as an argument: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Split#Parameters

Comment: and can you please tell how to identify number(digit) an same example ie e.innerHTML ='<p>Super By My 4 Story</p>'; i want to ignore digit from word count

Answer (score 0):

### Algorithm:

- Sweep through the entire html
- Perform regex replaces

  - replace <.*> (regex for anyting tat stays withing <>)by nothing
  - replace /&nbsp/ by nothing
- tip: can be done by replace function in javascript. hunt on w3schools.com

Now you have the clutter out!

then perform a simple word/character count